# Discontinuous functions in numerical integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integration

I have a system of ODEs whose time courses I'd like to numerically integrate. One of these should have a continuous strictly decreasing term and a discontinuous increasing term. It looks something like this:

```
d[A]/dt = -k*A over the whole interval
```

and additionally

```
d[A]/dt = c for t in every 10 steps (if t%10 == 0)
```

I have encoded the first one as ODE in [SBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBML), the 2nd one as discrete event. Using numerical solvers like LSODE or CVODE fail to integrate this, however, with a root finding error.

What is the best way to encode such an ODE in a way that the solvers above can handle?

---

Ok I found the issue:

```
d[A]/dt = c for t in every 10 steps (if t%10 == 0)
```

does not work because t does not need to be divisible by 10 at any point. The following works:

```
d[A]/dt = c for t in every 10 steps (if t%10 < 0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: usually for ODEs with discontinuous functions involved, it is a good idea to ensure that the routine/function in your computing environment supports "event detection"; Mathematica has the `Method -> {"EventLocator", (*sub-options*)}` for `NDSolve[]`, and the [FORTRAN routines by Hairer and Wanner](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/software.html) support this capability as well.

Comment: CVODE is supposed to support it as well.